# Is every measure translation invariant?

Tags: measure-theory

Is every measure translation invariant?

I ask the question because I noticed that this desideratum is always required when one introduces the Lebesgue measure, but is not mentioned in the general definition of a measure.

Comment: Actually, the **only** measure invariant by translation, is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: For every locally compact topological group there is a unique translation invariant measure called Haar measure, but all the other measures aren't invariant, for instance $\lambda_f(A) = \int_A f d\lambda$ won't be invariant if $f$ is non constant and $\lambda$ is invariant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure

Comment: @idm - any positive multiple of Lebesgue measure is also translation invariant.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider the measure $\delta(E) = \chi_E(0)$ defined on $\mathbb R$.